# struct alignment without argument and alignment on 16-bit target

Tags: c

I have some questions about struct alignment attributes without an argument. When declaring a structure with alignment like given below.

```
struct __attribute__ ((aligned))
{
     char a;
}s;
printf("%zu\n",sizeof(s));
```

output is 16.
  according to following link.
   http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

the compiler automatically sets the alignment for the type to the largest alignment which is ever used for any data type on the target machine you are compiling for.

It means I can't declare alignment greater than 16 byte. But if I give

```
struct __attribute__ ((aligned(32)))
{
     char a;
}s;
printf("%zu\n",sizeof(s));
```

then I am getting output 32.
It means we can declare greater than 16 byte alignment.
Then why are getting 16 byte? Is it compiler specific or target specific?

Alignment on 16 bit system — I read that there will not be any alignment issue on 16 bit system. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I think you misunderstand "data type."  The automatic alignment is for the largest integer, floating point, or pointer size native to that architecture. You can evidently align on bigger boundaries, it just won't gain you performance.

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler gets an unqualified `__attribute__((aligned))` attribute, it *defaults* to the largest necessary alignment on the machine.  That is not the same as saying 'you cannot set a larger alignment'; your test demonstrates that you can set a larger alignment explicitly.  You just won't get a bigger (or smaller) alignment unless you are explicit about it.

Comment: Thanks i understand, about alignment. But about alignment on 16 bit system. is there alignment issue will exist?, if it pointer holding address is not of the order of 2.

Comment: If you're asking "on a 16-bit machine, will there be problems reading 16-bit data from an address that is not a multiple of 2?", then the answer depends on the hardware.  For some chips (such as Intel), there will be a slow down but no exception; for other chips (M68k, for example, if you can still find them), there will be a bus error.

Comment: does it mean in 16 bit system alignment will be problem?, if pointer holding address is not 2's power oriented.

Comment: It depends on the hardware.  Some, maybe most, systems require 2-byte (16-bit) quantities to be aligned on an even address (an address that is a multiple of 2), and 4-byte (32-bit) quantities to be aligned on an address that is a multiple of 4.  Other systems don't.  Some 16-bit machines can require proper alignment; others may not.  You have to look at the hardware specs.

Comment: should functions be aligned on multiple of 4 for 32bit system? i read that there are instructions to make functions to aligned on multiple of 4. is compiler not taking care of it?

Comment: I wouldn't bother to worry about it; the compiler knows how to align functions and is unlikely to get it wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Leffler, please can you check -falign-functions in link http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: OK; I've looked at it.  Why should I worry about function alignment?  What is the use case for doing so?  What is the benefit of doing so?  Why have I not needed to worry about it for the last 30 years (bar a couple of months)?  Which compiler other than GCC (and `clang`/LLVM) supports it?  Why?  Which platforms does it provide a benefit on?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan Leffler, I have read that GCC is providing function alignment. but why are they providing this, not sure?